# How much do moq mock objects resemble the actual classes?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mvvm, moq

I'm new to unit tests and mocking. So please don't roast me :)

I wrote my first very simple unit test and it seems to work. But tbh I'm not getting what's going on. What I'm trying to test is, that the showDialog method is called with an argument of type EditViewModel when the OpenEditView() method of the main window is called. I'm using a dialog service to make my code satisfy the MVVM design pattern. And I'm using a factory to not directly create an object of a view model class directly in the method I want to test. The factory just creates and returns the object in asking it for.

When run, the test is passed.

How can this happen if I don't setup the CreateEditViewModel method of the ViewModelFactoryMock? What exactly is returned by the method when its called during the test? Or in a broader sense: How much do mocked objects resemble the actual object? When do I need to setup the methods of mocked objects?

**vm.OpenEditView()**

```cs
public void OpenEditView()
{
    EditViewModel viewModel = viewModelFactory.CreateEditViewModel(Argument1, Argument2, ...);
    bool? result = dialogService.ShowDialog(viewModel);
}
```

**Unit Test:**

```cs
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        // Arrange
        var DialogServiceMock = new Mock<IDialogService>();

        var ViewModelFactoryMock = new Mock<IViewModelFactory>();

        DialogServiceMock
            .Setup(x => x.ShowDialog(It.IsAny<EditViewModel>()))
            .Returns(true)
            .Verifiable();

        MainWindowViewModel vm = new MainWindowViewModel(DialogServiceMock.Object, ViewModelFactoryMock.Object);

        // Act
        vm.OpenEditView();

        // Assert
        DialogServiceMock.Verify(mock => mock.ShowDialog(It.IsAny<EditViewModel>()));
    }
}
```

**IViewModelFactory**

```cs
public interface IViewModelFactory
{
    EditViewModel CreateEditViewModel(Argument1, Argument2, ...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can this happen if I don't setup the CreateEditViewModel method of the ViewModelFactoryMock?

You do not actually do anything with what is returned from the mock so there was no opportunity for it to fail because the value was null.

> What exactly is returned by the method when its called during the test?

In this case the value of `viewModel` is *null* because no expectation was setup on the mock.

The test passes because the verification

```
DialogServiceMock.Verify(mock => mock.ShowDialog(It.IsAny<EditViewModel>()));
```

expects `It.IsAny<EditViewModel>()` which can include *null*.

If you wanted to verify the actual instance, then you can create one and setup the mock to behave as expected. Assuming `EditViewModel` is not `sealed`

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    // Arrange
    var DialogServiceMock = new Mock<IDialogService>();

    var ViewModelFactoryMock = new Mock<IViewModelFactory>();

    var viewModel = Mock.Of<EditViewModel>(); // Or new EditViewModel(...);

    ViewModelFactoryMock
        .Setup(_ => _.CreateEditViewModel(It.IsAny<Argument1>(),....));
        .Returns(viewModel);

    DialogServiceMock
        .Setup(x => x.ShowDialog(It.IsAny<EditViewModel>()))
        .Returns(true)
        .Verifiable();

    MainWindowViewModel vm = new MainWindowViewModel(DialogServiceMock.Object, ViewModelFactoryMock.Object);

    // Act
    vm.OpenEditView();

    // Assert

    //verify that the mocked view model was actually used.
    DialogServiceMock.Verify(mock => mock.ShowDialog(viewModel));
}
```

> How much do mocked objects resemble the actual object?

They (the mocks) are derived from the base type so they are implementations of the actual object/interface

> When do I need to setup the methods of mocked objects?

Only when their behavior is needed to exercise the test to completion.

Comment: But how comes that when I change `DialogServiceMock.Verify(mock => mock.ShowDialog(It.IsAny<EditViewModel>()));` to `DialogServiceMock.Verify(mock => mock.ShowDialog(It.IsAny<AlertBoxViewModel>()));` for example the test fails? I receive the following message: Expected invocation on the mock at least once, but was never performed: mock => mock.ShowDialog<AlertBoxViewModel>(It.IsAny<AlertBoxViewModel>())

Configured setups: 
IDialogService x => x.ShowDialog<AlertBoxViewModel>(It.IsAny<AlertBoxViewModel>())

Performed invocations: 
IDialogService.ShowDialog<EditViewModel>(null)

Comment: @Baconman that just proved my point. Note what is actually invoked. `IDialogService.ShowDialog<EditViewModel>(null)`. You set it up to expect one thing and then ask it to verify another. It will fail.

Comment: So... to make this clear to me: `IDialogService.ShowDialog()` is invoked in the original question with an object of value null and type EditViewModel? And that's because the mocked factory mocks the type of the return value of its methods but not the value? Btw. for my dialog service only the type of the given object matters.

Answer (score 0):

> How much do mocked objects resemble the actual object?

None much rather it's a mocked setup. MOQ is a *Dynamic Proxy* based based mocking system. So when you create a mock(Stub) of the interface (interface whose api you want to mock) it creates a proxy of that interface, in broad, it creates a proxy class by inheriting the actual type/interface under mock and `override` the specific method (That's why MOQ can only work with `virtual` or `abstract` method).

Thus when the actual api method gets called, your test runner make sure to call the interceptor method (Setup method) with any argument you pass and not with an actual argument.